# GRUB on SSD while elementary OS is on HDD

Tags: release-freya, grub, uefi, ssd

I have a Samsung laptop with an SSD (24GB) and an HDD (500GB). First, I installed windows 10 on the SSD, no problem so far. Then I installed latest build of elementary OS Freya on HDD but when I try to boot there's a GRUB issue. GRUB is on SSD (Even though I made a boot partition on the HDD) while the rest of the OS is in the HDD.

I'm not sure if this is the UEFI bug that people have been talking about, tho.

Answer (score 1):

When installer asks you how to install, (Only elementary, etc.), you must select "More", set partitions, choose the correct partition you want to mount as `/boot`, and correct device to install grub.